# After voluntarily left Uk , will I get visa to go back again?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, overstay

I had live Uk almost 8 and half years . I had overstayed there like 7 years . Firstly my visa was granted to uk and I went to uk as dependent visa from my country  . And after that I just stayed illegally there without re applying again  because I didn’t have any kind of way to apply . So I overstated there . And currently my husband now is French national .And we decided to go back to my own country with voluntarily departure . And I paid all my expenses all by my self . And went back to my country where me and my now husband got married there. And after 5 months I applied to France visa . And i got the visa again to go to France with my husband . And now I am in France and I have a resident permit here now . And my husband and I am planning to go to Uk to settle there together  as I will be applying for EEA family permit visa . And I know it’s been 1 year that I have left Uk . So I am eligible to apply . But still I am nervous to apply . And I checked the form as well . In there I have give the information about my last 10 years travel history as well . As I will write what the truth is . But still  i am getting nervous . Please could you reply me back  ? Would you think I will get visa in my situation? Please reply me back thank you very much

Comment: Related question https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/15684/previous-unlawful-stay-in-uk-how-can-my-husband-non-eu-get-family-visa

Comment: This question could use some copy-editing for clarity.